# How can I base a WPF style on a style that is in a compiled resource dictionary?

Tags: .net, wpf, resourcedictionary, basedon

I've downloaded the Reuxables free styles and added them as a resource dictionary to my App.xaml. I've also added my own resource dictionary that includes a validator template.

The problem is that when I add a style target type in my validator template to target a type of object, that type of object loses the style from the Reuxables library.

This is my App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/ReuxablesLegacy;component/edge.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Validator.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And this is my validator resource dictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:WPFLibrary.Converters;assembly=WPFLibrary">
    <conv:ErrorListConverter x:Key="errorListConverter" />
    <Style x:Key="myValidatorTemplate" TargetType="Control">
    <!-- If return from converter is 'true' (where converter is handed a dictionary and property name) then set the border and tooltip accordingly -->
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Value="true">
        <DataTrigger.Binding>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource errorListConverter}" ConverterParameter="EXISTS" >
            <Binding Path="ErrorList" />
            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Tag" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </DataTrigger.Binding>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" >
            <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource errorListConverter}" ConverterParameter="VALUE" >
                <Binding Path="ErrorList" />
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Tag" />
            </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <!--List the control types that should be able to display validation errors-->
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource myValidatorTemplate}" />
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource myValidatorTemplate}" />
    <Style TargetType="DatePicker" BasedOn="{StaticResource myValidatorTemplate}" />
    <Style TargetType="DataGrid" BasedOn="{StaticResource myValidatorTemplate}" />
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource myValidatorTemplate}" />
    <Style TargetType="GroupBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource myValidatorTemplate}" />
    <Style TargetType="TabItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource myValidatorTemplate}" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Because I'm applying the validator to textboxes, comboboxes, datepickers, datagrids, groupboxes and tabitems, all of these have lost their Reuxables Edge style.

I appreciate any solutions. Thanks!

Comment: I have used the code [here](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=384) to successfully make styles `BasedOn` multiple base styles, however I only tried it with named styles, not implicit styles. Perhaps it may work for you?

Comment: Rachel, thanks for that code, it's actually quite good but it doesn't seem to work with implicit styles, which is my main problem. I'm almost using Reflector to extract the XAML from the Reuxables DLL and modifying their style myself, but I'm not 100% on that being legal, I'll have to check.

Comment: I wasn't sure if it would work on implicit styles, but I had hoped you'd be able to modify it to work with them if needed. I'm not sure if you're aware or not, but you can base a style on an implicit style using this syntax: `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}"`

Comment: Yes, I know about basing a style on an implicit style, but somehow it didn't seem to work. I changed the line on my validator template style that declares it to <Style x:Key="myValidatorTemplate" TargetType="Control" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Control}}"> and I get an error: 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception.'